# Expo Location problem: watchPositionAsync does not return a value or returns it after a long time (even 10 minutes)

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location, expo

Good evening, I'm developing my first React Native Expo app for hobby purposes. It's an application that uses the mobile phone geolocation to track the user movements in order to organize a treasure hunt in the city.
But I'm having a problem: the watchPositionAsync function works very erratically. Sometimes the value of the location object is returned right away. Most of the time though, it doesn't get returned at all or even takes 10 minutes to do so.

This is the first version of the code, with only the function in question:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

const Navigator = () => {

 const [deviceLocation, setDeviceLocation] = useState(null);
 const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

 const getLocationAsync = async() => {
 let loc = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      timeInterval: 10000,
      distanceInterval : 20
    }, 
      (newLocation) => {
        setDeviceLocation(newLocation); 
      }
    );
  
  };

 getLocationAsync()

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (deviceLocation.location !== '') {
    text = JSON.stringify(deviceLocation.location);
  }
    
   return (
       <View>
            <Text>{text}</Text>
        </View>    
    )
}
```

This is the version with additional functions (such as calculating the distance from a predetermined point at each re-render of the watchPositionAsync function and setting a specific sentence to be communicated to the user):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import NavigatorUI from './NavigatorUI';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import { getDistance, findNearest } from 'geolib';


const treasureLocation = {
  latitude: 39.2695552,
  longitude: 8.4679172
}



const Navigator = () => {


  const [deviceLocation, setDeviceLocation] = useState({
    location : '',
    treasureDist : '',
    sentence: ''
  });
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  const getLocationAsync = async() => {
  let loc = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      timeInterval: 10000,
      distanceInterval : 20
    }, 
      (newLocation) => {
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, location: newLocation}); 
        getDistfromTreasure();
        switchDist();
        console.warn(deviceLocation.sentence) 
      }
    );
  
  };

  getLocationAsync()


  const getDistfromTreasure = () => {
    if(deviceLocation.location){
      let {latitude: deviceLat, longitude: deviceLong} = deviceLocation.location.coords;
      let {latitude: treasureLat, longitude: treasureLong} = treasureLocation;
    
        let dist = getDistance({
                                  latitude: deviceLat, 
                                  longitude: deviceLong 
                                }, 
                                {
                                  latitude: treasureLat, 
                                  longitude: treasureLong
                                } 
                                );
        
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, treasureDist: dist})   

    }

    };



  const switchDist = () =>{
    if(deviceLocation.treasureDist){
      let {treasureDist: val} = deviceLocation;
      if(val > 1000){
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, sentence: 'Example1'});
      }
      else if(val < 1000 && val > 500){
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, sentence: 'Example2'});
      }
      else if(val < 500 && val > 100){
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, sentence: 'Example3'});
      }
      else if(val < 100 && val > 50){
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, sentence: 'Example4'});
      }
      else if(val < 50){
        setDeviceLocation({...deviceLocation, sentence: 'Example5'});
      }

    }
    
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (deviceLocation.location !== '') {
    text = JSON.stringify(deviceLocation.location);
  }
    

    return (
           <>
             <View>
               <Text>{text}</Text>
             </View>

             <View>
               <Text>{sentence}</Text>
             </View>
        </>
    )
       
}

export default Navigator
```

In both cases the screen remains with the word 'Waiting' for an infinite time.
Also, in the second case, I noticed that the re-renders happen much faster or much slower than I set with the timeInterval option. In any case with discontinuous speed.

Has anyone had the same problem and managed to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

the code seems almost ok for me. I think that in the first code you posted there is an error in the last else if before the render. The location object given by expo contains a property coords, and you need to cehck if deviceLocation is defined before reading that.

```
  else if (deviceLocation.location !== '') {
text = JSON.stringify(deviceLocation.location);}
```

->

```
 else if (deviceLocation && deviceLocation.coords) {
 text = JSON.stringify(deviceLocation.coords)};
```

I also played a little bit with that code and i would write it as:

```
const Navigator = () => {
  console.log('render')

  const [permissionResult, setPermissionResult] = useState(undefined);
  const [deviceLocation, setDeviceLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  const getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    setPermissionResult(status)
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      return;
    }
  }

  const getLocationAsync = async() => {
    await Location.watchPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      timeInterval: 10000,
      distanceInterval : 20
    }, 
      (newLocation) => {
        setDeviceLocation(newLocation); 
      }
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // If permission request is not done
    if (permissionResult === undefined) {
      getPermissionAsync();
    }
  }, [permissionResult]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // If permission has been done and the result is available
    if (permissionResult !== undefined) {
      getLocationAsync()
    }
  }, [permissionResult])

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    console.log('errore')
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (deviceLocation && deviceLocation.coords) {
    text = JSON.stringify(deviceLocation.coords);
    console.log(deviceLocation)
  }
   
  return (
      <View>
          <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>    
  )
}
```

I hope this will help, and that I understand the problem